# MySQL column error on inner join

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, inner-join, mysql-workbench

I'm following a [tutorial](http://jugojava.blogspot.com/2011/02/jdbc-security-realm-with-glassfish-and.html), and want to create a user role view.  This is the first thing I've ever done with SQL, though I know some of the basics.  I'm using the MySQL Workbench.

My statement is like this:

```
CREATE VIEW `v_user_role` AS

SELECT  u.Username, u.Password, g.name

 FROM `users_groups` ug

 INNER JOIN `user_table` u ON u.iduser = ug.userid

 INNER JOIN `group` g ON g.idgroup =  ug.groupid;
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
ERROR 1054: Unknown column 'ug.userid' in 'on clause'
```

There's a foreign key in the users_groups table with the name userid.  What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: Describe for users_groups which just shows the id and not the foreign keys.  The select query mentioned below fails.

[image]

Comment: what are the columns on table `users_groups`?

Comment: it has an id, id_usersgroups; and two foreign keys, userid and groupid

Comment: in the tutorial, it has `_` unless you have renamed it.

Comment: I did rename a few tables/columns, but they definitely match.

Comment: If you renamed a few columns, _that's_ what you need to show us rather than the tutorial original. There's a possibility your renaming didn't work as well as you thought :-) First up would be checking the result of `select userid from users_groups` _exactly_ like that.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your SQL statement.  Please post your table definitions using `EXPLAIN` -- something is most likely named incorrectly...

Answer (score 0):

Since it's complaining about the `users_groups.userid` column, your _first step is to check that:

```
select userid from users_groups
```

With the renaming of table and column names, the most likely explanation is that you're renamed something wrongly.

It would be a lot easier if you supplied the actual schema rather than the tutorial link and, by that, I mean the schema output from MySQL itself with something like:

```
select * from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'user_table'
```

so as to avoid any transcription errors.